# React - Login screen flashes on Loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created a React app, which has a Login page, Loading page and the main app.

Unfortunately, when a user logs in - instead of only showing the Loading until the data is loaded - it flashes the Login page for a fraction of a second.

This is what I tried to do:

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const { user, logout } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
      const body = {...};

      if (body) {
        getDetails(body)
          .then((res) => {
            setData(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error getting company details:", err);
          })
          .finally(() => {
              insertData(body)
              .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Error inserting company data:", err);
              })
              .finally(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
              });
          });
      } else {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
  }, [user]);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Login}>
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Loading}>
        <Loading />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <Data />
```

Can you spot any bug in here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing `!isLoggedIn` to `!isLoading && !isLoggedIn` in your if condition

Comment: you can try moving `isLoading` above the `!isLoggedIn` block, and you can also avoid using the `isLoggedIn` state by simply using `if(!user) return <Login>`

Comment: and inside your `useEffect` you can `setIsLoading(false)` in the else block of `if(user)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent this flicker, you can initialize the isLoggedIn state to true, assuming that the user is already authenticated by default. Then, when the user is not available or the authentication fails, you can set isLoggedIn to false.

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(!!user); // Initialize isLoggedIn based on user
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const { user, logout } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const body = {...};

      if (body) {
        getDetails(body)
          .then((res) => {
            setData(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error getting company details:", err);
          })
          .finally(() => {
              insertData(body)
              .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Error inserting company data:", err);
              })
              .finally(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
              });
          });
      } else {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      setIsLoggedIn(false); // Set isLoggedIn to false when user is not available
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [user]);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Login}>
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Loading}>
        <Loading />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <Data />;
};
```